# Replace only when not in a pair

Tags: java

I have following string

```
<b>bold</b> ...... <b>bold1..... <b>bold2</b> <u>12333</u>
```

I want this

```
<b>bold</b> ...... &lt;b&gt;bold1..... <b>bold2</b> <u>12333</u>
```

i.e replace `<` and `>` only when if it doesn't complete `<b></b>` or `<u></u>` pair.

i was trying `replaceAll("<","&lt;")` `.replaceAll(">","&gt;")` but don't know how to avoid if there is a pair.

Comment: Okay. And your question is...? (Hint: What have you tried and where are you stuck?)

Comment: How important to you is this feature?

Comment: have you heard of Stack ?

Comment: actually i have a web app where in a post if user type `<b>bold</b>` the text should be bold

Comment: i was trying `replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">","&gt;")` but don't know how to avoid if there is a pair

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this with a simple `replaceAll()`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)<([a-z])>(?![^<]*</\\1>)", "&lt;$1&gt;");
```

This regex matches *any* open tag that isn't closed by a same-named tag.

Note that it is limited to non-nested tags. That is, the tag `<b>` in `<b><u>12333</u></b>` would be matched as "not closed".

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "<b>bold</b> ...... <b>bold1..... <b>bold2</b> <u>12333</u>";
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)<([a-z])>(?![^<]*</\\1>)", "&lt;$1&gt;");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
<b>bold</b> ...... &lt;b&gt;bold1..... <b>bold2</b> <u>12333</u>
```

Comment: Nice. I wonder if OP also needs to handle unpaired closing tags.

Comment: how to handle `<b x=''>bold</b>` if a tag has any attribute it shoud be encoded like `&gt;b x=''&gt; bold &lt;/b&gt;` strict rule is that it should be in the form of `<b>.....</b>`

Comment: @Manish that's a different question, and one with much wider implications. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a simple `replaceAll`. I suggest something like this (for `<b>...</b>` pairs; do it again for `<u>`/`</u>`):

1. Search the string and find the offsets of all the `<b>` strings. (A good data structure for this would be to push the offsets onto a stack.)
2. Do the same for all the `</b>` strings.
3. Working from the end (popping the stacks), check that the offsets pair up correctly (that is, that the last offset for `</b>` is greater than the last offset for `<b>` which, in turn, is greater than the next-to-last offset for `</b>`.
4. When you find a mismatch, make the appropriate substitution at the relevant offset. The logic for what to do in various mismatch situations (including handling one stack being empty) is left as an exercise for the reader. :)
5. Repeat until all offsets have been processed.

The reason to work from the end is so that when you substitute `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` you don't need to adjust the remaining offsets.

An alternative strategy would be to copy characters one at a time, suspending copying when you get to a `<` until you determine whether it is the opening of a matched `<b>` or `<u>` tag or whether some sort of substitution is required.

Comment: Depends. If it's known that tags are not going to be nested in the input, then a [simple `replaceAll()` can do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26113168/256196). The question is not clear, but the sample data suggests tags won't be nested.

Comment: @Bohemian - Nice answer! This is supposed to handle user input, so I have my doubts about tags not being nested.

Answer (score 0):

well - i'm not a friend of posting external libraries to provide help...

but since i have tried it and must say it **is** working properly i tell you about this:

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php#custom_tag_infos

the html-Cleaner reads html-data and cleans it...

if you have a **not-wellformed xml-document** the htmlcleaner will add/remove missing tags and **make a wellformed document** out of it!...

if you don't like an external library you must look at the answer from @Ted Hopp who has pointed out clearly how to solve your problem...